# How do you get an "uncertified copy of birth registration" certified?

Tags: ontario, birth-certificate

I received an "uncertified copy of birth registration" from the Registrar's office. It looks just like a regular photocopy. I need it to be certified for other official government business.

I simply get a notary to sign it?

If it came from the provincial registrar's office why would it be uncertified in the first place? Why isn't it "official"?

Comment: What jurisdiction is this (what province of what country?)  Usually, if you want a certified copy, you have to order a certified copy from the registrar or whatever office.  You can't get an uncertified copy certified after the fact.  In some places, a certified copy will only be given to the person named in the certificate or a close relative, so that possessing one is some sort of evidence that you are the person.

Comment: So basically, I think you have to take this up with the registrar.  Contact them and ask how you can get a certified copy, which usually would have an embossed seal or something of the sort.  You may have to provide some sort of proof of your identity in order to get it.

Comment: Hello. This post is related to this post. https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/41639/applied-for-adoption-records-original-birth-registration-its-not-the-origin . I ordered my own adoption order records. Nothing was closed. They say on their site they send you the adoption order an `uncertified copy of original birth registration`. I got both but why is it "uncertified"? http://www.forms.ssb.gov.on.ca/mbs/ssb/forms/ssbforms.nsf/GetAttachDocs/11315E-A~2/$File/TXT_11315E-A.htm. If you read at the top they state what they send you. It does say uncertified but why?

Comment: Another guess is that they won't give a certified copy of the original, because the information it shows is no longer true.  E.g., following your example, the child who was born is not *currently* named Tom Jones.  In that case, you might want to investigate whether your "other government business" really requires a certified copy of the original certificate, or whether they need a certified copy of the amended one instead.

Comment: Thanks Nate. I mean it sounds like a conspiracy. Someone doesn't want me to meet my clone? lol They have my (first) birth certificate on file. I know because I once held it in my hands. Just because I was adopted by my stepfather I am no longer privy to it? I have always been with my biological mother.  Anyway, besides all of this, it is my understanding that [if the adoption has no gag order on it], they are supposed to release the original `birth certificate` or `birth registration` document that WOULD have my name at birth. So that's why I'm wondering why it does NOT show my name at birth.

Comment: I think you're much more likely to get a useful answer by asking the registrar than asking random people on the Internet.

Comment: Most def. That's why I mention in my other thread I will be contacting them. But its the weekend so I'm just getting some ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Being not certified means the copy could be a fake. So nobody can certify it - unless they have the original to compare it. But even with the original present, I wouldn't want to certify anything unless I saw the copy being created from the original, so I think you need a new certified copy to be made.